# Req.data not showing up once sent to server with POST method (using connect middleware)

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I'm unable to get the `var data` I sent in via a `POST` method. This should be easy (right?), but I'm clearly missing something (either conceptually or a setting).

At this stage, I simply want to check to see if the `server side` code will output the data to the console. The array is being stringify-ed correctly, eg. `['one','two','three']`  becomes `0=one&1=two&2=three`
but I can't pull it out on the server side.

What am I missing?

**Client side**

```
var qs = require('querystring') 
  , http = require('http');

var some_array = ['one','two','three'];
var data = qs.stringify(some_array);

var options = { host: 'localhost',
                path: '/search',
                port: '3000',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'content-length': Buffer.byteLength(data),
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json' } 
                  }


function go_post(data) {
    req = http.request(options, function(res) {
          // do something with response       
    });
    req.write(data);
    req.end();
  };


  go_post(data);
```

**Server side**

```
 var connect = require('connect');
 var qs      = require('querystring');

 var server = connect.createServer();


server.use(function(req,res,next) {
if ( '/search' == req.url && req.method == 'POST' ) {   
            // quick check to see if data came through
    console.log('BODY IS ' + req.data);
    } else {
        next();
    };
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These objects arent available because they are still in the "raw" request. You have to use a middleware like `connect().use(connect.bodyParser())` in order to get them from the request via `req.data`.

Comment: Great. Thanks! That solved it. On the *server side code* I cut out `var qs = require('querystring');` and added `server.use('/search', connect.bodyParser());` and put the following in the middleware  to show the JSON: `console.log("request body is: %j",req.body);`